# Can a ReactRootView be nested (android)

Tags: android, react-native

I have an android application built already that I would like to use React Native in.  It's a large application and I don't want to migrate everything at once.  For example, my toolbar code is a bit complex and I'd like to leave it native for now.  So my layout looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
        android:id="@+id/react_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in onCreate() instead of creating a new ReactRootView I'm doing this:

```
mReactRootView = (ReactRootView) findViewById(R.id.react_root);
... // Other init
setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

However, I'm getting an error on setContentView(mReactRootView):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

This leads me to believe I cannot nest a React**Root**View inside other views.  How would I go about keeping my current Toolbar implementation, but still using React Native for the rest of the page?  I know this exists: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html  Is bridging to the native component my only option?

**Edit**: Followed Konstantin's suggestion below and here is what I have:

ReactFragment.java

```
public class ReactFragment extends Fragment implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.react_fragment, container, false);
    activity = getActivity();

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(activity);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(activity.getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(true)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();

    group.addView(mReactRootView);
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "AwesomeProject", null);
    mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(activity, this);
    return group;
}
// onPause() onDestroy() etc.
```

react_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/react_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Added to main_content.xml

```
...
<fragment
    android:name="com.amazon.kindlestore.main.ReactFragment"
    android:id="@+id/react_frag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
...
```

And in my main activity I'm adding the Fragment like this:

```
ReactFragment reactFragment = (ReactFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.react_frag);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.react_frag, reactFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This seems to be working, I have my react components rendering below my native Toolbar

Comment: i have same issue in my app. i need to use Custom Tab Bar that i use android native application. but now some part of my app is react native is there any possibility to just show/hide tab bar in react native using react native Bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a fragment for RN ui part and use it in your xml layout. In this fragment create `ReactRootView`, then create or obtain `ReactInstanceManager`, which you'll need to hook to fragment's lifecycle callbacks. And then you start your RN application inside the `ReactRootView` using this instance manager.

Check out this official [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) (don't forget to select Android in top menu)

Comment: I tried this and made some progress but things still aren't working.  Can you take a look at the edit I made to the question and see if I might be missing anything?

Comment: I've noticed you changed BundleAssetName, JSMainModuleName. Are you sure that your js bundle is available under those names? Do you provide js bundle asset when packagin your app or do you serve it from development node server? And do you use correct react component name, i.e. do you register it in your js code like `AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', ...`?

Comment: After posting that update I realized I was trying to nest my ReactRootView inside another ReactRootView.  I've changed react_fragment.xml to contain a FrameLayout instead of a ReactRootView and things seem to be working well. Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue in android can you please share working example of it.

Comment: If you look at the question under "Edit:" I've included code from ReactFragment.java, react_fragment.xml, main_content.xml, and my main activity java file.  This should be all the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

replace RelativeLayout with LinearLayout